# How can I find out who is (implicitly) calling my ToString?

Tags: c#, .net, tostring

My class requires additional information to properly output its status, so I've added a custom PrintSelf method taking the appropriate parameters.

However, I'm afraid there are still calls to ToString in my large project, which were not replaced by the new method. How can I find those improper calls to ToString?

I'm using VS 2015, but it does not seem to have this ability.

Throwing an exception in ToString would be an obvious way, but I don't want to do that for two reasons:

1. ToString can still perform a different job and output something not depending on the added parameter.
2. There is no way to get full code coverage, meaning it would only find a few instances of implicit calls, but not (reliably) all of them.

Comment: Log the callstack? And why not override ToString instead of having PrintSelf?

Comment: The idea of `ToString` is to give a text representation of your instance.  That should never require external input, since external input is not part of the instance.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check the callstack,

Comment: The idea is that the class cannot know enough of its environment by default (the environment may change anytime), so it has to be provided. ToString itself is fine for basic information, but for the complete picture, a second, custom method with parameters is required. If someone were to still call only ToString, it would generate invalid output.

Comment: I'm hoping for a method that does not require full code coverage. Anything that I need to put inside ToString suffers from this.

Comment: @mafu It sounds like your object should be implementing [`IFormattable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5):

To override ToString and log the caller you can do like this

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();           
        StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();  

        StackFrame callingFrame = stackFrames[1];
        MethodInfo method = callingFrame.GetMethod();
        YourLogingMethod(method.DeclaringType.Name + "." + method.Name);

        return base.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea and resolves the first of my two mentioned issues (ToString should still be usable for callers who do not require the more complex output).

-- Sadly, it does not solve the second (full code coverage).

Comment: im not sure what you mean by getting all of them ?  this method will give you the possiblity to log each caller to the ToString method?   do you have controll of the all source code calling this tostring method?  (in that case you could use a find usage search on the overidden method to find them within your solution

Comment: What I mean is that this requires all (im- or explicit) calls to ToString to be actually called during execution. I cannot guarantee that, as the code base is too large to check every line for possible calls.

Comment: When I use Visual Studio's 'Find References', I get all calls to any explicit (not implicit) ToString of any class (not just mine), which is very different from what I need. Is it different for you? Then I must have misconfigured my VS.

Comment: are you able totry this? Install jetbrains resharper , and then implement the tostring override method, then use find usage advanced on the overridden method , i think it should be able to find what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can make usage of the [Obsolete Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
public class MyFirstClass
{
    //true or false parameters indicates whether to throw 
    // a compile error (true) or warning (false)
    [Obsolete("Please use the method PrintSelf() instead of ToString()", false)]
    public overrides string ToString()
    {
        //Whatever code you want here
        return "";
    }
}

public class MySecondClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        mfc = new MyFirstClass();
        mfc.ToString(); //Here you will get a compiler warning
    }
}
```

So this will let you know inside Visual Studio of all the calls made to this function. Since it is only a warning, it is still possible to use it.

(note : Sorry if the syntax is not correct, I'm normally a VB .Net developper, feel free to correct it if needed.)

Comment: I don't think that will help, A call to `String.Format("{0}", myFirstClass);` would use `.ToString()` but would not throw a compiler warning/error.

Comment: I think Scott is right, but this is a good idea regardless - it provides automated, static analysis of explicit calls, and should at least prevent accidental further additions of (explicit) calls to ToString.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain correct, but at least (as stated by @mafu) user will be warned to not use it...